# jQuery find closest ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My HTML structure is like this:

```
    <div class="product-slider-title">
        <div><span class="left">&nbsp;</span></div>
        <div>Sample title</div>
        <div><span class="right">&nbsp;</span></div>
    </div>
    <div id="prslider1" class="product-slider-wrapper">
        <div class="left-prduct-slider-nav sprites"></div>
        <div class="right-prduct-slider-nav sprites"></div>    
        <div class="product-slider">
            <ul>
                <li class="product-holder"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     </div>
```

How can i find the closest `.product-slider ul` from `.left-prduct-slider-nav` when i click on `.left-prduct-slider-nav`?

Comment: @Nil : Open your eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if `this` is `.left-prduct-slider-nav` then

```
var ul = $(this).siblings('.product-slider').find('ul')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XW99q/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to search the siblings after current element and use `find()` to searched the children in the matched element returned by `nextAll`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QuzTa/)**

```
$(this).nextAll('.product-slider').find('ul');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var ul = $('.left-prduct-slider-nav').closest('ul');
```

Comment: This doesn't work since `.product-slider` is sibling with `.left-prduct-slider-nav`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try this:

```
$('.left-prduct-slider-nav').click(function () {
    var closest_ul = $(this).parent().find('.product-holder ul');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `first-child`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="product-slider-title">
    <div><span class="left">&nbsp;</span>

    </div>
    <div>Sample title</div>
    <div><span class="right">&nbsp;</span>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="prslider1" class="product-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="left-prduct-slider-nav sprites">Left Slider Nav</div>
    <div class="right-prduct-slider-nav sprites"></div>
    <div class="product-slider">
        <ul>
            <li class="product-holder1"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="product-holder"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="product-holder"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li class="product-holder"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="product-slider-title">
    <div><span class="left">&nbsp;</span>

    </div>
    <div>Sample title</div>
    <div><span class="right">&nbsp;</span>

    </div>
</div>
<div id="prslider1" class="product-slider-wrapper">
    <div class="left-prduct-slider-nav sprites"></div>
    <div class="right-prduct-slider-nav sprites"></div>
    <div class="product-slider">
        <ul>
            <li class="product-holder"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".left-prduct-slider-nav").click(function () {
        alert($(".product-slider").find("ul:first-child").find("li").prop("class"));
    });
});
```

#### jsFiddle.

#### Explanation:

I handle the `.click()` function of `.left-prduct-slider-nav` then I alert the `class` of the closest or in other words the first `ul:first-child`'s li.

#### Proof:

The proof is that I changed the `class` of the first `ul`'s `li` and then `alert()` it and then the output I get is this: `product-holder1`.

Answer (score 0):

The closest `.product-slider ul` from `.left-prduct-slider-nav` is just the first one in the list, so you can use `:first`:

```
$('.left-prduct-slider-nav').click(function() {

    $(this).parent().find('.product-slider ul:first')

})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$(this).next().next().find('ul');
```